# How to get coordinates of address from Python

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I need to geocode an address to a latitude, longitude pair to display on Google Maps, but I need to do this server-side in Django. I could only find reference to the Javascript V3 API. How do I do it from Python?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would suggest using [Py-Googlemaps](http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/). To use it is easy:

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
gmaps = GoogleMaps(API_KEY)
lat, lng = gmaps.address_to_latlng(address)
```

EDIT: If necessary, install `Py-Googlemaps` via: `sudo easy_install googlemaps`.

Comment: Is it possible to get API keys that work with this library anymore? I generated a Javascript v3 API key but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @powerj1984 I get a warning for malware when I try to access your link, is that normal or should I be worried?

Comment: When I posted the link there was no warning for malware. Not sure what's going on now.

Answer (score 26):

I would strongly recommend to use [geopy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy). It will return the latitude and longitude, you can use it in the Google JS client afterwards.

```
>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim()
>>> location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
>>> print(location.address)
Flatiron Building, 175, 5th Avenue, Flatiron, New York, NYC, New York, ...
>>> print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
(40.7410861, -73.9896297241625)
```

Additionally you can specifically define you want to use Google services by using `GoogleV3` class as a geolocator

```
>>> from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
>>> geolocator = GoogleV3()
```

Answer (score 6):

Google Data has an [API for Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) has a [REST-ful API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html) - and they also have a [Python library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) built around it already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code working for Google Maps API v3 (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14582003/304209)):

```
import urllib
import simplejson

googleGeocodeUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

def get_coordinates(query, from_sensor=False):
    query = query.encode('utf-8')
    params = {
        'address': query,
        'sensor': "true" if from_sensor else "false"
    }
    url = googleGeocodeUrl + urllib.urlencode(params)
    json_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    response = simplejson.loads(json_response.read())
    if response['results']:
        location = response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
        latitude, longitude = location['lat'], location['lng']
        print query, latitude, longitude
    else:
        latitude, longitude = None, None
        print query, "<no results>"
    return latitude, longitude
```

See [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) for the complete list of parameters and additional information.

Comment: this doesn't work anymore because google quires a personal API key to work: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

Comment: @skjerns thanks for the update! if it's easy to fix, feel free to update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Python package `googlemaps` seems to be very able to do geocoding and reverse geocoding.

The latest version of googlemaps package is available at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlemaps