# Get location coordinates using bing or google API in python

Tags: python, google-maps, coordinates, bing-maps, nltk

Here is my problem. I have a sample text file where I store the text data by crawling various html pages. This text contains information about various events and its time and location. I want to fetch the coordinates of these locations. I have no idea on how I can do that in python. I am using nltk to recognize named entities in this sample text. Here is the code:

```
import nltk

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    sample = f.read()

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(sample)
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
chunked_sentences = nltk.batch_ne_chunk(tagged_sentences, binary=True)

#print chunked_sentences
#print tokenized_sentences
#print tagged_sentences

def extract_entity_names(t):
    entity_names = []

    if hasattr(t, 'node') and t.node:
        if t.node == 'NE':
            entity_names.append(' '.join([child[0] for child in t]))
        else:
            for child in t:
                entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(child))

    return entity_names

entity_names = []
for tree in chunked_sentences:
    # Print results per sentence
    # print extract_entity_names(tree)

    entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(tree))

# Print all entity names
#print entity_names

# Print unique entity names
print set(entity_names)
```

Sample file is something like this:

> La bohème at Covent Garden
>
> When: 18 Jan 2013 (various dates) , 7.30pm  Where: Covent Garden,
>   London, John Copley's perennially popular Royal Opera production of
>   Puccini's La bohème is revived for the first of two times this season,
>   aptly over the Christmas period.  Sir Mark Elder conducts Rolando
>   Villazón as Rodolfo and Maija Kovalevska as Mimì. Mimì meets poet
>   Rodolfo (Dmytro Popov sings the role on 5 and 18 January) one cold
>   Christmas Eve in Paris' Latin Quarter.  Fumbling around in the dark
>   after her candle has gone out, they fall in love. Rodolfo lives with
>   three other lads: philosopher Colline (Nahuel di Pierro/Jihoon Kim on
>   18 January), musician Schaunard (David Bizic)  and painter Marcello
>   (Audun Iversen), who loves Musetta (Stefania Dovhan). Both couples
>   break up and the opera ends in tragedy as Rodolfo  finds Mimì dying of
>   consumption in a freezing garret.

I want to fetch coordinates for Covent Garden,London from this text. How can I do it ?

Comment: You really should have mentioned that 'your' code is just a copy of the example at https://gist.github.com/322906.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really have two questions:

1. How to extract location text (or potential location text).
2. How to get location (latitude, longitude) by calling a Geocoding service with location text.

I can help with the second question. (But see edit below for some help with your first question.)

With the old Google Maps API (which is still working), you could get the geocoding down to one line (one ugly line):

```
def geocode(address):
    return tuple([float(s) for s in list(urllib.urlopen('http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?' + urllib.urlencode({'output': 'csv','q': address})))[0].split(',')[2:]])
```

Check out the [Google Maps API Geocoding Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/):

Here’s the readable 7 line version plus some wrapper code (when calling from the command line remember to enclose address in quotes):

```
import sys
import urllib

googleGeocodeUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?'

def geocode(address):
    parms = {
        'output': 'csv',
        'q': address}

    url = googleGeocodeUrl + urllib.urlencode(parms)
    resp = urllib.urlopen(url)
    resplist = list(resp)
    line = resplist[0]
    status, accuracy, latitude, longitude = line.split(',')
    return latitude, longitude

def main():
    if 1 < len(sys.argv):
        address = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        address = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA'

    coordinates = geocode(address)
    print coordinates

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    main()
```

It's simple to parse the CSV format, but the XML format has better error reporting.

### Edit - Help with your first question

I looked in to `nltk`. It's not trivial, but I can recommend [Natural Language Toolkit Documentation, CH 7 - Extracting Information from Text](http://nltk.org/book/ch07.html), specifically, `7.5   Named Entity Recognition`. At the end of the section, they point out:

> NLTK provides a classifier that has already been trained to recognize named entities, accessed with the function nltk.ne_chunk(). If we set the parameter binary=True , then named entities are just tagged as NE; otherwise, the classifier adds category labels such as PERSON, ORGANIZATION, and GPE.

You're specifying `True`, but you probably want the category labels, so:

```
chunked_sentences = nltk.batch_ne_chunk(tagged_sentences)
```

This provides category labels (named entity type), which seemed promising. But after trying this on your text and a few simple phrases with location, it's clear more rules are needed. Read the documentation for more info.

Comment: @AnshuThakur, is there anything else I can do to make this answer more acceptable to you?

Answer (score 6):

Since September 2013, Google Maps API v2 [no longer works](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodingupgrade). Here is an updated version of great @jimhark's code, working for API v3 (I left out the `__main__` part):

```
import urllib
import simplejson

googleGeocodeUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

def get_coordinates(query, from_sensor=False):
    query = query.encode('utf-8')
    params = {
        'address': query,
        'sensor': "true" if from_sensor else "false"
    }
    url = googleGeocodeUrl + urllib.urlencode(params)
    json_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    response = simplejson.loads(json_response.read())
    if response['results']:
        location = response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
        latitude, longitude = location['lat'], location['lng']
        print query, latitude, longitude
    else:
        latitude, longitude = None, None
        print query, "<no results>"
    return latitude, longitude
```

See [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) for the complete list of parameters and additional information.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you want to do is called a geocode operation. Of course you will have to extract the 'location' information by your self inside the block of textual information.

You can do it using the service from:

- Bing Maps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx
- Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/
- Nokia Maps: http://developer.here.net/javascript_api_explorer

Please keep in mind that you should consider license that might applies to you depending on your use cases.