# finding lat and lon by inspecting html

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there an easier way to find the coordinates from the html of this url = https://www.sreality.cz/detail/prodej/byt/1+kk/praha-zizkov-krasova/151897164

I inspected the site but so far it doesnt look like there is any coordinates. the site is using mapy.cz

I tried to convert the adress to coordinates but the coordinates are sometimes off.

This is what i tried:

```
address = 'praha zizkov krasova'
url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/' + urllib.parse.quote(address) +'?format=json'

response = requests.get(url).json()
print(response[0]["lat"])
print(response[0]["lon"])
```

Comment: Dont't think tho cordinates are included in the html, but maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/32333188/20443541 helps you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can find the latitude and longitude values using the site's API:

```
https://www.sreality.cz/api/en/v2/estates/{property_id}
```

You can find the property_id on the property page's url (The long number at the end of the url). For the link you sent it's 151897164. This is an example for another [property](https://www.sreality.cz/en/detail/sale/house/family/kraluv-dvur-levin-vetrna/4257355596) from the same site:

```
import requests as r
property_id = 4257355596
postURL = f"https://www.sreality.cz/api/en/v2/estates/{property_id}"
results_post = r.get(postURL).json()
print("lat: ", results_post["map"]["lat"])
print("lon: ", results_post["map"]["lon"])
```

I can also suggest using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) as an alternative framework to crawl these stuff and also running this crawler on a spider management solution like [estela](https://estela.bitmaker.la/docs/estela/installation/main-guide.html) .